# Playstation 3 hardware problem

Tags: ps3

I got a PS3 of craigslist from a guy in my area (about 25 miles). It is an original 60GB piano black model with a card reader.

Anyhow, after the 3.55 system update it will not play Blu-Rays anymore. According to what I read online from searching, there was a problem with something like 1% of PS3 have a "bricked" Blu-Ray player after the update.

The drive still works, it just only plays PS2 (DVD) games, did not try any PS1 games.

What I am wondering is there any chance that upgrading the machine to system software 3.60 which came out would "unbrick" the Blu-Ray player?

If not is there anything else I could try?

Further more, if there is nothing else I can do, can someone point me to a reputable repair facility that can fix the system, the system is **OUT OF WARRANTY**

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I'd definitely try the 3.60 update.  While I don't know if it fixes the issue, I would doubt it could make things worse.

Comment: @ Matthew Read, That was my belief too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this isn't mentioned in the [3.60 release notes](http://us.playstation.com/support/systemupdates/ps3/) or the [3.56 release notes](http://us.playstation.com/support/systemupdates/ps3/history/index.htm#update356).  **I would recommend you perform the update.**  At worse, it doesn't fix the issue, and you're in the same state.  (It might have actually been the [3.50 update](http://us.playstation.com/support/systemupdates/ps3/history/index.htm#update350) that caused the issue.  Sony added support for 3D games/movies in that release.)

**I've never used a PS3 repair service, so can't recommend one.**  Have you tried Sony's [service page](https://service1.us.playstation.com/rma.htm?_flowExecutionKey=_cB40C2BD5-1740-6C54-28AF-6DCD82BD920B_k1B5A7BC2-69D5-B9D8-F6F3-FBDC5B6FCF01)?  It takes you through a bunch of steps to diagnose your problem.

If none of that works, **I would [call Sony](https://service1.us.playstation.com/rma.htm?_flowExecutionKey=_c7E3F7164-04C8-1921-FE30-583D76754E12_kF006F772-D5FB-CDD0-CB02-449D5F107E35)**.  They can probably refer you to an authorized repair dealer or may be aware of the issue and how to resolve it

Comment: Perfect answer, I called sony and found that my other original PS3 can also be fixed. @ $132 a pop :( Well at least they cover the shipping. Anyhow thanks.

Comment: That's awesome!  I was hoping they would do something like that.  Keep that backwards-compatible system working.  So worth the $132.

Comment: Lol, 2 people on my local piece of craigslist bought them for 100 a pop only 100 bucks to a new slim one!. Have no interest in the backwards compatible feature.